# Gradle Multi Project Dependencies with Multiple Lib folders

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I have a project that is laid out like the following:

```
abc/
    abc-core/
        abc-core-actions/
            abc-core-actions-a/
                src/
            abc-core-actions-b/
                src/
        abc-core-package/
            src/
    abc-framework/
        abc-framework-core/
            lib/
        abc-framework-dependencies/
            lib/
    abc-utility/
        src/
```

And within the `lib` folders in the `abc-framework` project are a bunch of jars that represent the core framework and the dependencies required for the framework to function.

What I want to accomplish is anything under `abc-core` and `abc-utility` to have available to them the `lib` jars.

I found that doing something like this:

```
project(':abc-core:abc-core-actions') {
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: '../../abc-framework/abc-framework-core/lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
        compile fileTree(dir: '../../abc-framework/abc-framework-dependencies/lib', includes: ['*.jar'])
    }
}
```

Did work but this means for each section (abc-core:abc-core-actions-a, abc-utility, and etc.) I have to include a section like above and its also relative.

Ideally I would like to define that all subprojects have a fileTree dependency to those folders but the issue is the path changes depending on the subproject.

So what would be the best way to have the `compile fileTree` reference the `abc` project's absolute path?

Comment: Something like `project(":abc-framework").projectDir + "/abc-framework-core/lib"`?

Comment: Thank you! I ended up going with at the top `def frameworkCore = "${project.projectDir}/abc-framework/abc-framework-core/lib"` and then under `subprojects` in the `dependencies` section went `compile fileTree(dir: frameworkCore, includes: ['*.jar'])`. I then removed the `abc-framework` items from my `settings.gradle` file since they weren't being compiled.

Comment: Sounds good. Do you want to write that up as an answer, or would you like me to?

Comment: You can write it up, then I'll set it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in `projectDir` property of any project to build an absolute path relative to one of your projects, assuming that all your projects participate in the same multi-project build.

So if you have a `build.gradle` file at the top-level `abc` directory, that would probably look something like this (based on your comment above):

```
//"project" here equates to the root project, i.e. "abc"
def frameworkCore = "${project.projectDir}/abc-framework/abc-framework-core/lib"
def frameworkDeps = "${project.projectDir}/abc-framework/abc-framework-dependencies/lib"
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: frameworkCore, includes: ['*.jar'])
        compile fileTree(dir: frameworkDeps, includes: ['*.jar'])
    }
}
```